# XML Node Disappear

Tags: c#, xml

I need to get 2 nodes.

```
<OrderItem>
  +<Product PNR="FFQK2P" Type="Hotel">
  +<Product PNR="SACN8L" Type="Flight">
<OrderItem>
```

Each Product node have two same nodes. They are "PriceInfo" and "SearchParameters". I get them from;

```
XmlNode xmlHotelPriceInfo = orderItem.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode("OrderItem/Product/PriceInfo");
XmlNode xmlHotelSearchParametes = orderItem.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode("OrderItem/Product/SearchParameters");
```

So I appent nodes;

```
xmlHotel.AppendChild(xmlHotelPriceInfo);
xmlHotel.AppendChild(xmlProductItemInfo);
xmlHotel.AppendChild(xmlHotelSearchParametes);
orderItem.AppendChild(xmlHotel);
```

That code creates nodes perfectly. In the first product;

```
<Product PNR="FFQK2P" Type="Hotel">
    <PriceInfo>
    <ProductItemInfo
    <SearchParameters>
</Product>
```

The codes are in for loop. In the second cycle;

```
xmlFlight.AppendChild(xmlFlightPriceInfo);
xmlFlight.AppendChild(xmlProductItemInfo);
xmlFlight.AppendChild(xmlFlightSearchParametes);
orderItem.AppendChild(xmlFlight);
```

It appends second product. But it removes PriceInfo and SearchParameters from first nood. It looks;

```
<Product PNR="FFQK2P" Type="Hotel">
    +<ProductItemInfo>
</Product>
<Product PNR="SACN8L" Type="Flight">
    +<PriceInfo>
    +<ProductItemInfo>
    +<SearchParameters>
</Product>
```

But I need to get like;

```
<Product PNR="FFQK2P" Type="Hotel">
    +<PriceInfo>
    +<ProductItemInfo>
    +<SearchParameters>
</Product>
<Product PNR="SACN8L" Type="Flight">
    +<PriceInfo>
    +<ProductItemInfo>
    +<SearchParameters>
</Product>
```

Why is that occur?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're adding the same element to two parents. That won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the `AppendChild` method, you just change the owner (parent) node of the child node.
Have a look at the [CloneNode method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.clonenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So your code should be similar to:

```
xmlHotel.AppendChild(xmlHotelPriceInfo);
xmlHotel.AppendChild(xmlProductItemInfo);
xmlHotel.AppendChild(xmlHotelSearchParametes);
orderItem.AppendChild(xmlHotel);

...

xmlFlight.AppendChild(xmlFlightPriceInfo.CloneNode(true));
xmlFlight.AppendChild(xmlProductItemInfo.CloneNode(true));
xmlFlight.AppendChild(xmlFlightSearchParametes.CloneNode(true));
orderItem.AppendChild(xmlFlight);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild.aspx

First you need to `CreateElement` and then `AppendChild`.